# can't share post from website to FB page

Tags: wordpress, post

Ran url through debugger and got this. but don't know how to fix it? Any help is greatly appreciated!!!!

> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value
>   can be inferred from other tags. Missing Properties The following
>   required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image,
>   og:description, fb:app_id Bad Response Code URL returned a bad HTTP
>   response code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a plugin that enables Open Graph tags, such as Yoast WP SEO, and make sure you're setting a featured image, title tag, meta description, and have entered your FB app ID into the plugin. This could be a problem with theme (i.e. they don't have any `<title>` tag set) or it could just be you need to add a plugin to add the other details FB requires.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Yoast WP SEO. It is a commonly used plugin for managing open graph tags. The free version is all you'll need.

[Yoast SEO Plugin](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/)

Comment: yes have yoast installed already. was working fine, all of a sudden it just stopped. rest of social feeds work just fb???

Comment: @JackRosenberg Take a look in the rendered source code. Do you see a comment like this `<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO plugin v5.4.1 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->`?  If not, Yoast isn't outputting to the document head.

Comment: I could not find that specific line. But the latest yoast plugin is installed?

Comment: If it's not displaying, that means that the plugin is not able to output to the head element correctly.  Assuming this a custom theme, check that you've include wp_head() in the head element to allow Yoast to add the appropriate meta elements.